# Angular-UI-Bootstrap - Modal Dialog scope issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to AngularJS and am trying to figure out a simple way of displaying a modal dialog (using Angular-UI-Bootstrap) for $http call errors and pass the error text from the calling controller to the $scope used by the dialog's template.

I've created a Plunker to illustrate my issue at: http://plnkr.co/edit/nMdjJ256tH9oA9kRpUtV?p=preview

See line 21 in example.js for what I'm attempting to do.

Thanks in advance,
NY

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: the dialog template has placeholders for {{error.title}} and {{error.text}}. how do I pass these values from the calling controller when opening my modal dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass external values to dialog controller you set `resolve` option appropriately. Then the resolved objects will be available as parameters in the dialog controller.

[HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/eRQV7zOqwsoInq7MnFv5?p=preview) is the corrected version of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass a custom scope to your modal's controller (at least on `ui-bootstrap` version 0.8.0). This way, your `DialogController` does not depend on the resolved object all the time; if you don't pass that object, you will get an injection error.

In the application I'm working on, we call the `DialogController` from different places and only in some cases, we need to pass some data.

You can see this working here: http://plnkr.co/edit/jn94Zl?p=preview

It all depends on your specific needs.